# Where is the error IE is finding in this script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object

IE continues to give me an error on the next-to-last line stating "Object required".  I am not sure where the issue would be.  Any advice?

```
function showdiv()
{
  document.getElementById("dialogue").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("screen").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("screen").style.width = getBrowserWidth();
}
function hidediv(opt){
if(opt=="agree"){
  document.Annexation.checkbox.checked = true;
  document.getElementById("dialogue").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("dialogue").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("screen").style.display = "none";
}else{
  document.getElementById("dialogue").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("screen").style.display = "none";
}}

window.onscroll = scrollEvent;
function scrollEvent() {
var y;
if (document.documentElement && !document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  // IE6 +4.01 but no scrolling going on
  y=document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop){
  // IE6 +4.01 and user has scrolled
  y=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
else if (document.body && document.body.scrollTop){
  // IE5 or DTD 3.2
  y=document.body.scrollTop;
}
  document.getElementById("screen").style.top = y+"px";
}
```

Comment: Why you don't just use PrototypeJS, jQuery or any other JavaScript-Framework? They make cross-browser support easy!

Comment: You have a null object. Debug your code.

Comment: @Javaguru - How can you justify suggesting Slevin adopt an entire framework for a simple operation like this?

Comment: Do you also get an error in Firefox?  If so, along with the Firebug extension, Firefox is a much better development tool. The error message given there will be much more informative.

Comment: I am using Firebug which does not see this specific error.  It only draws attention to a different one but I am going through one at a time.

Comment: @Sparafusile: Why not? I actually also like to reinvent the wheel, sometimes, but most the time it is way simpler to use some existing code. Another thing is: Once you started using a JS-framework you begin asking yourself: Why didn't I use this framework for all my projects? It SIMPLIFIES life, and improves readability of your code!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following probably returns null:

```
document.getElementById("dialogue")
document.getElementById("screen")
document.Annexation
document.Annexation.checkbox
```

or `getBrowserWidth` is not defined.

Comment: This script is part of a main.js file that encompasses a whole site.  On this specific page, "dialogue" nor "screen" are present.  I'm assuming this is what would cause them to return as null?

Comment: @Slevin: if `showdiv` or `scrollEvent` or `hidediv` are called, and `screen` or `dialogue` does not exist, that will cause an error, yes. you can insert, as first line in each of these functions, the following `if(!document.getElementById('dialogue') || !document.getElementById('screen')) { return; }` which will abort the function when any of the DIVs don't exist

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("screen")` Is undefined. Add the following code:

```
if( !document.getElementById("screen") ) alert( "Spara was right." );
```

and it will tell you if that is the case or not.

Comment: Spara, I added that line above the document.getElementById("screen") and it did return the alert (which made me laugh by the way).  How can I resolve this?  Can I set that "screen" as a variable and assign it to be 0 or something?

Answer (score 0):

What does Annexation standar for in `document.Annexation.checkbox.checked = true;`

You have 2 ways to select a checkbox. One is assigning a name value for the tag of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="ck" />
```

`document.getElementsByName("ck")[0].checked = true;` to make the checkbox checked.

Another method is assigning an id for  the tag of checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="ck" />
```

`document.getElementById("ck").checked = true;` to make the checkbox checked.

Comment: Unigg, Thanks for the insight.  Unfortunately, this is not code I have written so I am still learning my way around everything and the way my predecessor had organized things.